# Issue with .net 4 connecting with TLS 1.0

Tags: .net, ssl

I have some .net 4.0 software communicating with a web service using HttpClient.
The web server was recently updated, and since then SSL/TLS communications have failed for a lot of my customers.
I have traced the SSL handshake and compared ciphers and TLS version (TLS 1.0) from my application to Internet Explorer, and both IE and my application offer the same ciphers.

I have found a single reference to someone with a similar problem: http://forums.iis.net/post/2088610.aspx.
His problem was solved by installing .net 4.5 - and actually so are mine.

I would like to know whether someone knows exactly what the changes are in .net 4.5 that make it work, and if there is a hotfix for .net 4.0 which will solve the problem for my customers without installing 4.5.

Comment: Is RC4 the *only* offered cipher? TLS + RC4 was killed off in a recent .Net patch

Comment: The server offers these ciphers (according to SSL Labs):
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA

Comment: The TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA cipher was chosen by the server in the Server Hello message. It is one of the ciphers that the .net client offers.